# Get elements in JSON array that contain an array that contains specific string value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following JSONs in my Postgres 12.2 DB:

```
{
  "foo" :[{"bar": []}]
}
```

```
{
  "foo" :[{"bar": ["a"]}]
}
```

```
{
  "foo" :[{"bar":["a", "b"]}]
}
```

Each of those JSONs is a different row in my table.
I want to write a query that would return to me the 2nd and 3rd josn but not the 1st (the JSONs that contains "a" in the "bar" array inside "foo"

Comment: You can use json_each_text('"a"')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the containment operator.

```
select * from table1 where column1 @> '{"foo":[{"bar":["a"]}]}'
```